# How to add animations to a ListView in Windows RT?

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I've got the following ListView defined in xaml:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="20,0"
                ItemsSource="{Binding UIModel.CommandHistory}" 
                SelectionMode="None" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" >
            </ListView>
```

When I add multiple Items to the bound ObservableCollection, the items are loaded all at once. Is there a way to make them load cascading?

Comment: I guess you'd have to override ObservableCollection and limit the list in CollectionChanged to only trigger *one* item at a time.

Comment: @Patrick that's the only problem? how to do that?

Comment: Uhm.. override ObservableCollection and its OnCollectionChanged method..

Comment: Check out the answer over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910215/listbox-item-load-animation

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241002/how-to-set-animations-transitions-when-adding-elements-to-a-listviews?rq=1