# How to disable animation when adding items to list view

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How can I disable the animation when adding a new item to list view?

[How to set animations/transitions when adding elements to a ListViews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241002/how-to-set-animations-transitions-when-adding-elements-to-a-listviews)

I tried this example, but it does not show any list footer for my list.

I have tried doing this:

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
            <ContentThemeTransition />  <!-- omit AddDeleteThemeTransition -->

        </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
    </ListView>
```

But that does not run, it crashes when I start the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this quirk as noted in the [documentation for `ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitions` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainertransitions.aspx):

> **Important** The XAML syntax for properties that have a **TransitionCollection** value is unusual in that you must declare an explicit **TransitionCollection** object element as the value, and then provide object elements as child elements of **TransitionCollection** for each of the transition animations you want to use. For most other XAML collection properties you could omit the collection object element because it can be implicit, but **TransitionCollection** doesn't support the implicit collection usage.

Try this XAML instead:

```xml
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <ContentThemeTransition />  <!-- You can even omit this transition if desired -->
        </TransitionCollection>
    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
</ListView>
```